# Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 7,Token in error = t

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-ce

Please help me, I have this code in a local website that sometime succeed and some times it doesn't.
When i check the event viewer from the server is see this error:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
There was an error parsing the query. 

[ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 7,Token in error = t ]

   at Test4.ISITPROC.subBtnP_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
```

That is my code:

```
// Create New Process Function
public void createProc(EProc proc)
{
    localDBConn sqldb = new localDBConn();
    sqldb.connectDB();
    string stSQL =
        "INSERT INTO Process (pID, reqID, engID, moduleName, priority, projTeam, estProjDur, startDate, finishDate, description, comments)"+ "VALUES('";
    stSQL += proc.pID + "','" + proc.ReqID + "','" + proc.EngID
        + "','" + proc.ModuleName + "','" + proc.Priority
        + "','" + proc.ProjTeam + "','" + proc.EstProjDur
        + "','" + proc.StartDate + "','" + proc.FinishDate
        + "','" + proc.Description + "','" + proc.Comments + "')";
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(stSQL, sqldb.sqlCon);

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqldb.closeDB();
    }
    catch (Exception eX)
    {
        sqldb.closeDB();
        throw new Exception("cDocument: Error occurred "
            + Environment.NewLine + eX.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use parameter to set value http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.parameters(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Does this structure is the reason ?

Comment: I used this structure in the whole website but this is the only one that has this issue :/

Comment: By using your code, it might be error in case some field of proc contains `'` character. You should refer this link about sql injection, too http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: What is `stSQL` at the moment of the error? Add that line to the errorlogging.

Comment: Thanks Tu Tran i will change it and all the function.

Comment: Thanks Hans Kesting I will add it to see if there are any other problems